# KendoReact StockChart: Navigator don't scroll

Tags: kendo-react-ui

We are using Kendo-React Library (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/stockchart/). The stockChart work as expected, but the navigator on the botton cannot be scrolled on the X-Axis.

We importing `HammerJs` follow the docs instructions : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/troubleshooting/

[image: kendo-react stockchart]

any idea why ? Tnx in advance

We tested using just the example, and work correctly, so.. something on the full page interact or is the root of the problem, but we don't understand what can be.